# SBT test does not work for spark test

Tags: apache-spark, sbt, derby

I have a simple spark function to test DF windowing:

```
    import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SparkSession}

    object ScratchPad {

      def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
        spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
        get_data_frame(spark).show()
      }

      def get_data_frame(spark: SparkSession): DataFrame = {
        import spark.sqlContext.implicits._
        val hr = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(List(
          ("Steinbeck", "Sales", 100),
          ("Woolf", "IT", 99),
          ("Wodehouse", "Sales", 250),
          ("Hemingway", "IT", 349)
        )
        ).toDF("emp", "dept", "sal")

        import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
        import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

        val windowspec = Window.partitionBy($"dept").orderBy($"sal".desc)


        hr.withColumn("rank", row_number().over(windowspec))

      }
    }
```

And I wrote a test like so:

```
    import com.holdenkarau.spark.testing.DataFrameSuiteBase
    import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
    import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
    import org.scalatest.FunSuite

    class TestDF extends FunSuite with DataFrameSuiteBase  {

      test ("DFs equal") {
        val expected=sc.parallelize(List(
          Row("Wodehouse","Sales",250,1),
          Row("Steinbeck","Sales",100,2),
          Row("Hemingway","IT",349,1),
          Row("Woolf","IT",99,2)
        ))

        val schema=StructType(
          List(
          StructField("emp",StringType,true),
          StructField("dept",StringType,true),
          StructField("sal",IntegerType,false),
          StructField("rank",IntegerType,true)
          )
        )

        val e2=sqlContext.createDataFrame(expected,schema)
        val actual=ScratchPad.get_data_frame(sqlContext.sparkSession)
        assertDataFrameEquals(e2,actual)
      }
```

}

Works fine when I right click on the class in intellij and click "run".
When I run the same test with "sbt test", it fails with the following:

```
    java.security.AccessControlException: access denied 
    org.apache.derby.security.SystemPermission( "engine", 
    "usederbyinternals" )
        at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
        at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884)
        at org.apache.derby.iapi.security.SecurityUtil.checkDerbyInternalsPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        ...
```

And here is my SBT script, nothing fancy-had to put in hive dependency, otherwise the test would not compile:

```
    name := "WindowingTest"

    version := "0.1"

    scalaVersion := "2.11.5"


    libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.2.1"
    libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.2.1"
    libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % "2.2.1"
    libraryDependencies += "com.holdenkarau" %% "spark-testing-base" % "2.2.0_0.8.0" % "test"
```

Google search points me to derby-6648 (https://db.apache.org/derby/releases/release-10.12.1.1.cgi)

which says:
Application Changes Required
Users who run Derby under a SecurityManager must edit the policy file and grant the following additional permission to derby.jar, derbynet.jar, and derbyoptionaltools.jar:

permission org.apache.derby.security.SystemPermission "engine", "usederbyinternals";

Since I did not explicitly install derby (probably used by spark internally), how do I do this?

Comment: Same problem here after upgrading 2.2.0 -> 2.2.1

Comment: Can you run `spark-shell` and execute `spark.range(5).show`? Does this work for you?

Comment: This worked as expected-I got +---+
| id|
+---+
|  0|
|  1|
|  2|
|  3|
|  4|
+---+

Comment: Here's spark ticket for same: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-22918

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Folowing quick and dirty hack solves the problem

```
System.setSecurityManager(null)
```

Anyway as it's related to automated tests only maybe it's not that problematic after all ;)

Comment: This solved it for me-and yes since it is an automated test, it is fine. The larger issue still remains though.

Comment: Finally ended up using: override implicit def enableHiveSupport:Boolean=false   which works fine

Comment: It would work only if you are not using Hive features :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a cleaner way then inside `build.sbt`:

```
test in Test := {
  System.setSecurityManager(null) // SPARK-22918
  (test in Test).value
}
```

This will apply the fix to all tests in all files without touching the test's code.

Comment: for some reason this doesn't work. It works when I manually add the line in all tests though

Comment: For a more recent version of SBT that would be: `Test / testOptions += Tests.Setup(() => System.setSecurityManager(null))`

Answer (score 0):

By default hive use two Metastores first one meta store service, and second the database called by default metastore_db and it uses derby. so i think you have to install and configure derby with hive.
But i have not seen the use of hive in your code.
I hope my answer help you

Comment: Right, had to use hive else the test framework (Dataframesuitebase) does not compile. I am not using hive.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this line in the test class to disable hive  worked for me

```
      override implicit def enableHiveSupport: Boolean = false
```

Got it here:

https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base/issues/148

Comment: That's OK as long as you don't need actual Hive emulation during tests. In some cases you need hive support enabled and still be able to run tests :)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by excluding wrong version of Derby and including right in `build.sbt`:

```
project.settings(libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"org.apache.derby" % "derby" % "10.11.1.1" % Test)
  .map {
      case module if module.name.contains("spark") => module.excludeAll(
          ExclusionRule(organization = "org.apache.derby"))
      case module => module
  })
```

It doesn't use hacks. Just manual dependency resolution.