# How can I configure, disable, or override the sbt SecurityManager?

Tags: sbt, java-security-manager

I'm trying to embed Apache Derby into an application.  When I run it directly from IntelliJ, everything works fine, but `sbt run` generates the exception:

`Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied org.apache.derby.security.SystemPermission( "engine", "usederbyinternals" )`

This seems to relate to the SecurityManager that SBT uses.  Are there ways to disable, reconfigure, or override the default SBT SecurityManager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JGC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6252525/jgc) provided [the insight in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50232040/error-running-spark-in-a-scala-repl-access-denied-org-apache-derby-security-sy).

In the relevant app:

```
System.setSecurityManager(null)
```

Alternatively, one could simply provide a preferred security manager in this way.